# How can I get the current directory with correct spelling?

Tags: winapi

I can get the path of the current directory using `GetCurrentDirectory()` but it always seems to inherit the spelling of PowerShell's current directory. For example, let's suppose I have a directory structure named `Test\MyProgram` on volume `D:`. Now if I do this in PowerShell:

```
 cd D:/test/myprogram
 ./myprogram
```

Then `GetCurrentDirectory()` will return `D:\test\myprogram` as the current directory because that's what I passed to `cd` but as described above, it is `D:\Test\MyProgram` in reality.

Of course, upper and lower case characters don't make a difference on Windows, but still: How can I get the real name of the current directory, with the correct spelling?

Comment: for what ? you can open folder and then query filesystem for name, say via `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` but for what ? name which you have at begin also correct, otherwise you can not open folder and query it "real" name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only the file system know how file names stored internally. so only way - open handle for path and then query file system about path. say via [`GetFinalPathNameByHandleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew) api. but note - you at begin need have correct path - otherwise you fail open file. so i think usually no sense do this

```
// here path returned by call GetCurrentDirectoryW

HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(path, 0, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);

if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    if (PWSTR szFilePath = new WCHAR[MAXSHORT])
    {
        if (GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hFile, szFilePath, MAXSHORT, FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED))
        {
            DbgPrint("%S\n", szFilePath);
        }
        delete [] szFilePath;
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

also note that we can use `FILE_NAME_OPENED` instead `FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED`. difference here - that in case we use `FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED` - the [`GetFinalPathNameByHandleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew) do extra query to file system - [`FileNormalizedNameInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/20bcadba-808c-4880-b757-4af93e41edf6#Appendix_A_Target_125) asked. This information class is [implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/d4bc551b-7aaf-4b4f-ba0e-3a75e7c528f0#Appendix_A_125) on *ReFS* and *NTFS* file systems. Other file systems return `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST`. if say true i dont know when  [`FileNormalizedNameInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/20bcadba-808c-4880-b757-4af93e41edf6#Appendix_A_Target_125) return different name than [`FileNameInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ne-wdm-_file_information_class). so on practice call with `FILE_NAME_OPENED` work bit faster and give the same result as `FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED`

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. It should be noted, though, that it requires at least Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Call `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` passing a file handle and `FileNameInfo` as the `FileInformationClass` argument. You'll need to do this for each component on your path.

Comment: not think that this the best. we need first open file and then call `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` with `FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED` . and this need only once do, not for each component. but anyway i not view big sense in such normalization

Comment: problem with `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` - that it return only file path inside filesystem - without device name (or driver letter if want) - if this is ok - can and better use this api. if we need full path with device - need use `GetFinalPathNameByHandle`