# How to get canonical filename on a case-insensitive filesystem?

Tags: c, filenames, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Imagine I have a file `foO/bar.txt`.

On a case-insensitive filesystem, I'm able to open the file as `FOO/BaR.tXt`.

Now I would like to detect the "canonical" filename (`foO/bar.txt`), so I could warn my users, that they should use the correct spelling if they want their save-files to be usable on systems with case-*sensitive* filesystems.
(that is: my users can insert relative paths via a text-input; on Windows they sometimes use non-canonical cases; when the project is then opened on a case-sensitive system, the relative paths are broken)

The entire code is in plain old C, and should work cross-platform (Linux, macOS, Windows; the latter two being the obvious candidates for case-insensitive filesystems...)

I tried using `glob()` (using the filename as the pattern), hoping that it would return the canonicalized filename, but alas! it does not. also the Windows equivalent `FindFirstFile()` will happily return the queried filename, rather than return the filename as found on disk.

Any idea for a simple solution that involves only stdlib?
(ideally without manually reading the content of the directory and then checking whether there's an exact match...)

Comment: There is nothing for this in the standard C library.

Comment: What *is* "the correct spelling if they want their save-files to be usable on systems with case-sensitive filesystems"?

Comment: I was going to suggest reading the content of the directory using `opendir` and `readdir`, but that's what you said you didn't want to do.  (Also it's a lot of work if, as in your example, you want to worry about variant spellings of the containing directories.)

Comment: NTFS should use something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58680545/1462295 , I believe this will fail for FAT

Comment: Note that MSVC function [`_findfirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/findfirst-functions?view=msvc-170) when asked to find `"teST.c"` reports `"test.c"` the actual file name.

Comment: umläute, Consider a solution using `opendir(), readdir)_, ...`. Then if that is too slow, ask for improvements.  As is, the request here is for substantial code.

Comment: that's what i feared. but thanks anyhow :-)

Comment: `FindFirstFile` *should* work and is what we used at my previous employer. (IIRC, we had to call `FindFirstFile` in a loop, I think for each directory component.) Also see [Getting actual file name (with proper casing) on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74451/).

Comment: POSIX doesn't provide any functions for case-insensitive matching of file names, AFAICS, but macOS does provide extensions such as `FNM_CASEFOLD` to `fnmatch()` provided that you haven't set too strict a set of macros for 'POSIX only'.